# Microphone access in Python

Tags: python, windows, microphone

Can I access a users microphone in Python?

Sorry I forgot not everyone is a mind reader:
Windows at minimum XP but Vista support would be VERY good.

Comment: What OS is this for?  Does it have to be cross-platform?

Comment: Useful answers in this more recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936828/how-get-sound-input-from-microphone-in-python-and-process-it-on-the-fly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to go about it would be to use the ctypes library and use WinMM from that.  mixerOpen will open a microphone device and you can read the data easily from there.  Should be very straightforward.

Comment: Do you think you can provide some sample code for this? I can call mixerGetNumDevs but i'm not sure how to get from there to mixerOpen or for reading levels. TIA

Answer (score 18):

I got the job done with [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)

It comes with a binary installer for windows and there's even an example on how to record through the microphone and save to a wave file. Nice! I used it on Windows XP, not sure how it will do on Vista though, sorry.

Comment: "Note that PyAudio currently only supports blocking-mode audio I/O.

PyAudio is still super-duper alpha quality."  from website

Answer (score 2):

You might try [SWMixer](http://code.google.com/p/pygalaxy/wiki/SWMixer).

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update to [Martinez' answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247349/), I also used [pyAudio (latest edition is 0.2.13 since Dec 26 2022)](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

Here's how to install pyaudio on windows (I did it in a virtual environment):

```
pip install pyaudio   # as of python 3.10 this should download a wheel
```

Once you have it installed, assuming you want to record into a 16-bit wave file, this snippet adapted from the [documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#record-example) should help:

```
import wave      # this will probably also need to be installed
import pyaudio

RATE = 16000
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16-bit frames, ie audio is in 2 bytes
CHANNELS = 1             # mono recording, use 2 if you want stereo
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024        # bytes
RECORD_DURATION = 10     # how long the file will be in seconds

with wave.open("recording.wav", "wb") as wavefile:
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    wavefile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wavefile.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wavefile.setframerate(RATE)

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True)
    for _ in range(0, RATE // CHUNK_SIZE * RECORD_DURATION):
        wavefile.writeframes(stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
    stream.close()

    p.terminate()
```

I wasn't able to use `with` for the `stream` handler, but this might be possible in future editions of pyAudio.