# Get system volume (Sound level) in linux using Python

Tags: python, linux, audio, volume

I am using Fedora 16 and modifying a program in python 2.7.

How do I get the systems volume (Sound level)?

Comment: Likely depends on if the system is using alsa, pulseaudio, or OSS (not likely since alsa has OSS compatibility). Good luck.

Comment: Kindly refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936828/how-get-sound-input-from-microphone-in-python-and-process-it-on-the-fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ALSA, use [`pyalsaaudio`](http://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html#mixer-objects)

For Pulse, its a bit raw. There are [ctype bindings](https://github.com/Valodim/python-pulseaudio)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ALSA, you can run 'amixer' to dump the state of all volume controls. For PulseAudio, I believe 'pacmd dump' should get similar info. (see http://blog.waan.name/pulseaudio-setting-volume-from-command-line/ )

Comment: To apply this answer in Python, you would just use a system call, e.g. popen or similar.