# Audio recording for skype via python

Tags: python, skype

I have not tried anything yet but I am looking for some kind  of pointers to show me the right direction. I want to write a script in python to record the conversations from skype. How can I write a program that records the conversation while conversations are made through skype? My platform is windows.

What I want to do:

1. Activate the python script (loop) to record as soon as the skype conversation starts.
2. record the conversation.
3. exit from the loop.
4. wait for the next conversation.

Update: I looked into Pyaudio and I can do the recording part now. However, I am still confused about how to let my program know that the voice session is activated and closed in skype.

Comment: Try [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)

Comment: Could you explain some more what exactly you want to do? (Examplary usage describing user who would do x,y,z ... would be good!)

Comment: take a look here

[Get sound input from microphone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936828/how-get-sound-input-from-microphone-in-python-and-process-it-on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen it?
[Skype for Developers](https://dev.skype.com/)

Comment: They do not seem to have methods to record the conversation. I might be looking for a direct thing, that might be might mistake.