# How to get the frequency of the input from mic

Tags: frequency, faust

I'm trying to analyze the input mic sound and get the frequency value of the input.

Is there any library I can get a frequency of the input?

I'm using FAUST.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly look here: [How get sound input from microphone in python, and process it on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936828/how-get-sound-input-from-microphone-in-python-and-process-it-on-the-fly)

Faust shouldn't matter too much other than worrying about async issues.