# What is the easiest way to access a a computers microphone in Python?

Tags: python, audio, microphone

I need to get some numbers so I can generate random numbers using ambient sound.

I want something on this level
pseudo code:

```
import microphone
p = pitch.get()
print p
```

Edit:

This is in Windows 7, BTW

Comment: Using ambient sound will not be very random at all.  Unless your microphone can listen to atom-level harmonic vibrations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microphone access in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193789/microphone-access-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the platform.  On Windows, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193789/microphone-access-in-python) has some answers; for Linux, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936828/how-get-sound-input-from-microphone-in-python-and-process-it-on-the-fly) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is as easy as you would like but I know that it is possible to access the microphone with [tksnack](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/man/snack2.2/python-man.html). I think it is available on main platforms.

microphone access should be possible with the record method of the Sound class

I hope it helps